# How can I tail dmesg

Tags: linux

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I am trying to monitor the serial port connect with my Arduino.
I have seen my friend using the following command (he performed it in my laptop):

```
tail -f {dmesg,syslog} | grep -i tty
```

And whenever I plugin and unplug the arduino, the terminal always keep up showing serial port name, its condition. But when I try it myself, it says that there is not such file or directory. I have search and tried following command:

```
tail -f var/log/dmesg
tail -f var/log/{dmesg,syslog}
```

But it seems like it does not show up the serial port or keep up with condition. Would you help me with any ideas?

Comment: You're probably missing a slash in front of `var` ?

Comment: Use `dmesg -w`.

Comment: Yeah I did dmesg -w and it work. But slash infront of var? I am gonna try it later

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
dmesg -W | grep -i tty
```

`-w, --follow`

> Wait for new messages. This feature is supported only on systems with a readable /dev/kmsg (since kernel 3.5.0).

So Output will be something like this

```
rexter@rexter:/media/rexter/REXDRIVE$ dmesg -w | grep -i tty
[    0.112876] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[  332.500320] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
```

If you want to get only new message and want to hide the old ones then use `-W`

`-W, --follow-new`

> Wait and print only new messages.

Bonus:
Use `-T` to get the time stamp so that you can get the time when you receive the log.

Thank you :)

Comment: `dmesg -wT` is a great combo!!